# show submit button js

Tags: javascript, php

check_availability.php

this is my php to check the form if it is already exist.

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");
//code check email
if (!empty($_POST["CUSUNAME"])) {
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) FROM tblcustomer WHERE CUSUNAME='" . $_POST["CUSUNAME"] . "'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $email_count = $row[0];
    if ($email_count > 0) echo "<span style='color:red'>Username is already used.</span>";
    else echo "<span style='color:green'>Username is available.</span>";
}
// End code check email
//Code check user name
if (!empty($_POST["PHONE"])) {
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) FROM tblcustomer WHERE PHONE='" . $_POST["PHONE"] . "'");
    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_row($result1);
    $user_count = $row1[0];
    if ($user_count > 0) echo "<span style='color:red'>Phone is already used.</span>";
    else echo "<span style='color:green'>Phone number is available.</span>";
}
// End code check username
?>
```

LogSignModal.php

here is my page.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for=
           "CUSUNAME">Username:</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input class="form-control input-sm" onBlur="checkUserNameAvailability()"  id="CUSUNAME" name="CUSUNAME" placeholder=
             "Username" type="text" value="">                                 
      <span id="username-availability-status"></span>                                           
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for=
           "PHONE">Contact Number:</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input class="form-control input-sm" onBlur="checkPhoneAvailability()" id="PHONE" name="PHONE" placeholder=
             "Phone Number" type="number" value="">                                       
      <span id="Phone-availability-status"></span>             
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <label class="col-md-4" align = "right"for=
           "image"></label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Sign Up"  class="submit btn btn-pup"  />
      <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" type=
              "button">Close</button> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
<script>
  function checkUserNameAvailability() {
    $("#loaderIcon").show();
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "check_availability.php",
      data:'CUSUNAME='+$("#CUSUNAME").val(),
      type: "POST",
      success:function(data){
        $("#username-availability-status").html(data);
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();
      },
      error:function (){}
    });
  }         
  function checkPhoneAvailability() {
    $("#loaderIcon").show();
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "check_availability.php",
      data:'PHONE='+$("#PHONE").val(),
      type: "POST",
      success:function(data){
        $("#Phone-availability-status").html(data);
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();
      },
      error:function (){}
    });
  }
</script>
```

my code is all worked, but I can't make a submit button to appear when the value I input in textbox is available in database and disappear if it is already use.

I hope someone help me, thank you.

Comment: Do you get any exception?

Comment: no sir, I saw some tutorials in different site, but it is using checkbox, I wonder if it is possible with textarea

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** First, you should definitely also check the comment of Dharman and rewrite how you fetch data from MySQL in your PHP code since the current state is vulnerable to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and is absolutely not safe to use!

The problem is how you pass your data to your ajax function. The way you do it, the server receives nothing but a plain string, for example `'CUSUNAME=dave'`. This way `$_POST["CUSUNAME"]` will find nothing and your server response will stay empty. So you should pass your data as an object the following way :

```
<script>
  function checkUserNameAvailability() {
    $("#loaderIcon").show();
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "check_availability.php",
      data:{'CUSUNAME': $("#CUSUNAME").val()},
      type: "POST",
      success:function(data){
        $("#username-availability-status").html(data);
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();
      },
      error:function (){}
    });
  }         
  function checkPhoneAvailability() {
    $("#loaderIcon").show();
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "check_availability.php",
      data:{'PHONE': $("#PHONE").val()},
      type: "POST",
      success:function(data){
        $("#Phone-availability-status").html(data);
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();
      },
      error:function (){}
    });
  }
</script>
```